# Capture the right button click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm playing around abit with winforms and its controls and just discovered how to do custommade buttonclicks. However, there is a problem. I've got a loop, that's looping through a list of elements, and if a condition appears - I'm creating a button that will pop up a gridview.

```
public void draw(ref Panel inputPanel) //draws the eventline
    {
        int stepCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < DaysList.Count-1; i++)
        {
            Button b1;
            if (DaysList[i].Elements.Count > max)
            {
                b1 = new Button(); //Create the box
                b1.Width = 120;
                b1.Height = 40; //Set width and height
                b1.Location = new Point(stepCounter + 35, 70); //Location
                inputPanel.Controls.Add(b1); //
                b1.Text = "Check event date in grid";
                b1.Show();
                b1.BringToFront();
                b1.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => btn_Click(sender, e, DaysList[i].Elements));
                stepCounter += 200;
            }
         }
     }
```

That was my method for creating the buttons and a click event for the when my condition appears. The function that is passed to the eventhandler looks like this:

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, List<EventElement> inputElems)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        DataGridForm window = new DataGridForm(inputElems);
        window.Show();
    }

public class EventElement
{
     public EventElement()
     {
     }
     public int Count{get;set;}
     public string Date{get;set;}
}
```

The clickpart of the event is fine but whenever i click the spawned buttons, I get the wrong data into the gridview.   As an **example**: The loop has created four buttons for me and they are presented on a straight line on the form. But whenever i click one of the buttons - dosnt matter which one of them, the button always return the data of the last spawned button. A more clear example: lets say we have the list inputElems looks like this:
    inputElems[0].Count -> 2644
    inputElems[1].Count -> 2131
    inputElems[2].Count -> 8467
    inputElems[3].Count -> 5462
When i now click the second button, the input to the second buttons parameter list should have the values (sender, e, 2131), right? but for some reason, the last argument gets the same like the 4th element in the list, even though i call the secondly created button.

I figured that it has something to do with me always calling the last added button_click to the eventhandler of the button, if so, how do I call different clicks from the EventHandler?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in the `ctor` for `DataGridForm`, where is that code?

Comment: The problem lays in the inputElems not getting the correct values, not in the datagrid

Comment: And what ***exactly*** do you mean by that? Is it the wrong value? If so, edit your question with what value you're getting vs. what value you would expect. See, that kind of information would actually be useful in helping solve the problem.

Comment: Will do!, increasing the example

Comment: Updated, better? Or you need even more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing inputElems with the EventHandler, you can use Tag.

E.g. use:

```
b1.Tag=i;
```

Then in your click event handler:

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        DataGridForm window = new DataGridForm(DaysList[int.Parse(button.Tag.ToString())].Elements);
        window.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `for` loop is out of scope, and thus unable to provide you with the data you're looking for. A more straight forward approach might be something like this:

```
public void draw(ref Panel inputPanel) //draws the eventline
{
    int stepCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DaysList.Count-1; i++)
    {
        Button b1;
        if (DaysList[i].Elements.Count > max)
        {
            b1 = new Button(); //Create the box
            b1.Width = 120;
            b1.Height = 40; //Set width and height
            b1.Location = new Point(stepCounter + 35, 70); //Location
            inputPanel.Controls.Add(b1); //
            b1.Text = "Check event date in grid";
            b1.Show();
            b1.BringToFront();
            b1.Tag = DaysList[i].Elements;
            b1.Click += btn_Click;
            stepCounter += 200;
        }
     }
 }
```

and then in `btn_Click`, do this:

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    int inputElems = (List<EventElement>)button.Tag;
    DataGridForm window = new DataGridForm(inputElems);
    window.Show();
}
```